# How can I make a basic program that allows someone to sign in to an account previously created?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python program that will allow a user to sign up or sign in, and I am currently doing so by creating a file that stores every **username** and its **password**. Right now, it is not writing to the file, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Please forgive me if it is a stupid error, I am not very experienced with python, but I can still make a basic program. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import sleep

def signin():
  usrlist = open("users.txt", 'w+')
  complete = False
  while (complete == False):
    usr = raw_input("Username: ")
    pwd = raw_input("Password: ")
    usrinfo = (usr + ":" + pwd)
    if (usrinfo in usrlist.read()):
        print("Welcome back " + usr + ".")
        complete = True
    else:
        print("Username or Password incorrect. Please try again.")
def signup():
  usrlist = open("users.txt", 'w+')
  usravailable = False
  while (usravailable == False):
    newusr = raw_input("Please choose a Username: ")
    if (newusr in usrlist.read()):
        print("Username taken. Please choose again.")
    else:
        usravailable = True
  newpwd = raw_input("Please choose a password: ")
  oldusrlist = usrlist.read()
  usrlist.write(oldusrlist + newusr + ":" + newpwd + ".")
  print("Thank You. Please Sign in.")
  signin()

print("Please Choose An Option:")
print("1. Sign In")
print("2. Sign Up")
inorup = input()
if (inorup == 1):
    signin()
elif (inorup == 2):
    signup()
```

Also, if you have any suggestions about how I could do this differently, or better(even if it's using a different language) Thank you and I appreciate your help.

EDIT:
If anyone can give me information on doing a program like this either using JSON, javascript, or multiple files that can store larger amounts of data about each account, please tell me how in the comments or an answer. I appreciate the help.

Comment: please fix alignments

Comment: Use sqlite3 to store your data is better than use a single file, you can  `import sqlite3` to use it

Comment: You need to fix your file modes. I hope this is just a toy program, and you don't actually intend to store real passwords like that. I guess if your program is offline it's not so bad. But still, some people use a small pool of passwords for everything, and its irresponsible to store such information on a machine that might be compromised.

Comment: Daoctor - Thanks! I will try.

Comment: BTW, Python 2's `input` function is a security hole. So (once the other problems with your program are fixed) at your "Please Choose An Option:" prompt the user can do virtually _anything_: see the passwords of all the other users, delete files from your hard drive, etc. As a safe demo, try entering `sleep(30)` at that prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your not saving issue, you need to do two changes:
1) in your signin() routine, change the line 'usrlist = open("users.txt", 'w+')' into 'usrlist = open("users.txt", 'r')

2) in your singup() routine, after the line 'usrlist.write(oldusrlist + newusr + ":" + newpwd + ".")', add: 'usrlist.close()'
Then you should be able to see the stuff got saved.

Comment: Thanks! This helped, and I can see that it is working, but it is not checking for an already taken username, and it will write over the previous data, I tried using the append method of opening, but it didn't work.

Comment: To fix that, in your signup() routine, change your first line 'usrlist = open("users.txt",'w+')' into 'usrlist = open("users.txt",'r+')'.

Comment: As 'w+' means Opening a file for both writing and reading and overwrites the existing file if the file exists and if the file doesn't exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.

Comment: I changed to append mode, and added other small changes, and it worked. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to use json

```
import json
import os

FILENAME = "./f.json"

# init the data file

def init_data():
    with open(FILENAME, "wb") as f:
        json.dump({}, f)

def load_content():
    with open(FILENAME) as f:
        infos = json.load(f)
    return infos

def save_content(content):
    with open(FILENAME, "w+") as f:
        json.dump(content, f)
    return True

def save_info(username, password):
    infos = load_content()
    if username in infos:
        return False
    infos[username] = password
    save_content(infos)
    return True


def sign_in(username, password,):
    status = save_info(username, password)
    if not status:
        print "username exists"

def login(username, password):
    infos = load_content()
    if username in infos:
        if password == infos[username]:
            print "login success"
            return True
        else:
            print "password wrong"
            return False
    else:
        print "no user named %s" %username


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    # here is some simple test    
    os.system("rm -f %s" %FILENAME)
    if not os.path.exists(FILENAME):
        init_data()

    # login fail
    login("hello","world")

    # sign_in
    sign_in("hello", "world")

    # login success
    login("hello","world")

    # sign_in fail
    sign_in("hello", "world")

    # login fail
    login("hello", "hello")
```